# close roscore after running with roslaunch

Tags: ros, roscore, rosmaster, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have a roslaunch that i run two node with it in my pc, but when i close both of them, roscore are still is running, any tip appreciated. it is the output of my roslaunch:

```
vahid@vahid:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch jur_gui_segmentation jur_gui_segmentation.launch 
... logging to /home/vahid/.ros/log/39b07ff0-16a4-11e4-815e-0024beb250ed/roslaunch-vahid-13418.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://vahid:58428/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    jur_gui_segmentation (jur_gui_segmentation/jur_gui_segmentation)
    jur_opencv_segmentation_node (jur_opencv_segmentation/jur_opencv_segmentation_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [13432]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 39b07ff0-16a4-11e4-815e-0024beb250ed
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [13445]
started core service [/rosout]
process[jur_gui_segmentation-2]: started with pid [13457]
process[jur_opencv_segmentation_node-3]: started with pid [13458]
 -1 
 
[jur_gui_segmentation-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/vahid/.ros/log/39b07ff0-16a4-11e4-815e-0024beb250ed/jur_gui_segmentation-2*.log
[jur_opencv_segmentation_node-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/vahid/.ros/log/39b07ff0-16a4-11e4-815e-0024beb250ed/jur_opencv_segmentation_node-3*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188052/close-roscore-after-running-with-roslaunch/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you add the `required="true"` option to one of the `<node>` tags in your launch file, roslaunch will shut down when that node exits. This includes stopping any of the other nodes that are running and then stopping the roscore, if it was started.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2